# Logstash Parsing Application Log

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

Trying to parse a particular log format via logstash and I'm after a few pointers really.. I've got logstash reading the file and sending the output to ElasticSearch, but I need to break the log down into additional fields, so that I can actually do something with the data..

My Log is in the followng format, I'm trying to capture the values in between the tags

```
<Tag>5<\Tag><Tag1>999<\Tag2><User>abcde<\User>
```

Any ideas on how I should approach parsing this file...

Thanks

I've now discovered 'mutate' and 'gsub', but for some reason or another I get the following error.. This is my Filter..

filter {
 if [type] == "xcp-stats" {

```
    mutate {
            gsub => [
            "fieldname", "/", "\\"
            ]
    }

    # match timestamp and add to variable @timestamp
    # Current 20150519T06:43:04
    date {
            match => [ "logdate", "yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss" ]
            target => "@timestamp"
     }

    grok {
            match => [ "message", "(?<usercount>[0-9])" ]
    }
 }
}
```

I get the following error everytime when parsing through the --configtest parameter.

Error: Expected one of #, {, ,, ] at line 31, column 15 (byte 830) after filter {

Any ideas

Comment: Mutate the \ to / and then use the xml{} filter?

Comment: Okay, I will investigate further..  thanks for the advice.